# Airflow incorrectly always picks the built in default credentials under Admin-> Connections

Tags: airflow

I am trying to connect to mysql database using MySqlHook. Under Admin -> Connections I have defined a new connection of the type mysql with the name myappname_db. I have used this in my code as `drupalHook = MySqlHook(conn_name_attr='myappname_db')`

However, when I run the dag in local, I see that it picks up the built in default credential from Admin -> Credentials i.e. mysql_default instead of myappname_db

To rectify this do I need to update any setting in airflow.cfg or any other config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The MySqlHook uses an attribute `mysql_conn_id` to store the connection id.

`conn_name_attr` refers to the name of the attribute (`mysql_conn_id` in this case), which is fetched dynamically in the MySqlHook.

Comment: Thank you so much. Changing ```drupalHook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='myappname_db')``` resolved the issue.